# Explain the types of Raga Sarang

Tags: indian-classical

Explain the `'Thaat'` of different kinds of raga Sarang. Which type of raga Sarang belongs with which Thaat?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question.

Basically, Vrindavani Sarang is considered to be the original form of Sarang, and the *aroh* and *avaroh* of this raga are S R m P N S'/S n P m R S.
As you can see, both variants of *nishaad* (*shuddha* and *komal*) are used, and *gandhaar* is absent. Yet, this raga is placed in the Kafi Thaat. The reason for this is that it has a structure very similar to Raag Kafi with the omission of *dhaivat* and *gandhaar*. As for the *shuddha ni,* the use of it in the *aaroh* is quite a typical feature in other Kafi Thaat ragas too. For instance, Raag Miya ki Malhar, Raag Bahaar, etc.

Pt. Vijay Koparkar explains why Sarang is placed in the Kafi Thaat in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSMwWEAJdPk&ab_channel=Ch-02%3ASANSKRITI%5BArts%2CHistory%2CPhilosophy%5D).

Moving on, Madhmaad Sarang is almost exactly like Vrindavani Sarang, except that it does not use the *shuddha ni* in the *aroh.* It uses the *komal ni* in both *aroh* and *avaroh*. S R m P n S' / S' n P m R S.

Shuddha Sarang, which has recently gained greater popularity, is somewhat different from the previous two ragas. Its *aroh* and *avaroh* are S R M P N S' / S' N D P M P m R 'N S. I think the reason it is called "Shuddha" Sarang is because it uses *shuddha ni* instead of the more typical *komal ni* used in Sarang ragas. But notice how both variants of *madhyam* (*shuddha* and *tivra*) are also used.

This makes classifying Shuddha Sarang more confusing, but some *vidvaans* place it in the Kafi Thaat because it is a type of Sarang, while others place it in the Kalyan Thaat because of the use of *tivra madhyam.*

As you can see, the Thaat system is not flawless. It is quite a useful system for classifying ragas based on the notes they use, but when a raga uses fewer than 7 notes, or when it uses both variants of a certain note, it becomes difficult to classify it under a Thaat without giving rise to some questions.

The *raagaang* classification, meanwhile, classifies ragas into "families" based on their origins, history, and structure, rather than simply the set of notes they use. Under this classification, all the Sarang ragas are placed in the Sarang family.